# Batch file that can create folder and subfolder from 1 PDF title and Move it into subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a reoccurring job that requires me to file PDFs with the names all structured "RMAfile PO#000001 SN#000002.pdf" and what I need is a way to create folder based on the SN# and a Sub Folder within each based off the PO# and then move the file into the subfolder.

Example...

```
C:\...\Desktop\RMAfile PO#000001 SN#000002.pdf
Run Batch file
C:\...\Desktop\000002\000001\RMAfile PO#000001 SN#000002.pdf
```

I've seen similar questions for creating folder based off of file names but none with this specific need.

Comment: This is not a free code/script writing service, so you need to show your efforts and tell us where you are stuck! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Anyway, you probably want this: `for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=# " %A in ('dir /B "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\RMAfile PO#?????? SN#??????.pdf" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"[^#][^#]* PO#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] SN#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf"') do @(mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%~nE\%C" & move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%A %B#%C %D#%E" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%~nE\%C\")`

Comment: Apologies if it seemed like I was just requesting free code. First question asked here. Was hoping for help with this problem I having trying to write it myself. The help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=# " %%A in ('
    dir /B "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\* PO#?????? SN#??????.pdf" ^| ^
    findstr /I /R /C:"[^# ][^# ]* PO#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] SN#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf"
') do (
    mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nE\%%C"
    move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%A %%B#%%C %%D#%%E" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nE\%%C\"
)
```

The `findstr` part just filters the files to avoid movement of wrong ones. If there are only files that match the described pattern anyway, you could reduce the code to this:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=# " %%A in ('
    dir /B "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\* PO#?????? SN#??????.pdf"
') do (
    mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nE\%%C"
    move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%A %%B#%%C %%D#%%E" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%%~nE\%%C\"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `for` command you can do it. See below.

```
@echo off

pushd C:\...\Desktop

for /f "delims=# tokens=2,3" %%i in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
   for /f "tokens=1" %%k in ('echo^(%%i') do set "po=%%k"
   set "sn=%%~nj"
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   mkdir "!sn!\!po!" >nul
   move "RMAfile PO#!po! SN#!sn!.pdf" "!sn!\!po!" >nul
   endlocal
)

popd
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great with a little tweaking for file locations.